# Use Angular interpolated string in CSS content property

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using the CSS **content property** `content: attr(myValue);` in an Angular 7 component's .css file

```
&::before {
    content: attr(myValue);
    position: absolute;
    left: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 1em;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: .785rem;
}
```

which is connected to a string value in the component's .html file like this:

```
      <div class="timeline-item" myValue='Can I use an interpolated value here instead?'>
        ...
      </div>
```

I want to insert an interpolated string value in the myValue in the .html.  I have tried the various bind techniques outlined in the official [Angular template syntax guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) without any success.

Is there a way to insert the interpolated value in myValue?  In other words, can I do the equivalent of this:

```
      <div class="timeline-item" myValue='{{myInterpolatedString}}'>
        ...
      </div>
```

Comment: currently not on a computer but i think you should use " instead of '. then it could work i think

Comment: Thanks @Isitar.  Looks like that worked: `attr.myValue="{{observation.observationDateTime}}`.  I am sure I had tried that because it is included in the Angular guidance I quoted in my question

Comment: @Isitar - if you add it as answer I will mark is as the accepted answer - when you get to a computer... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind an unknown property like `myValue` on a div to a value, the runtime is giving you an error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'myValue' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
<div class="timeline-item" [ERROR ->]myValue="{{'something'}}">
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@4:31
```

You have to use `attr.myValue` instead. It is possible to use single quotes `'` aswell as double-quotes `"`.

```
attr.myValue="{{myBoundValue}}"
attr.myValue='{{myBoundValue}}'
```

You could ommit the curly braces by using this syntax

```
[attr.myValue]="myBoundValue"
```